# React Native Switch Selector

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native

Very simple but yet still struggling. Essentially I need a function which automatically switches between the two options "user" and "business" from the switch selector without the user actually having to manually click the options on the screen.

Tried using:

const switchRef = useRef(null);

and

switchRef.current?.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);

with ref={switchRef} within the switch selector but this didn't work.

Here is the entire code for the switch selector:

```
<SwitchSelector
    initial={0}
    onPress={(value) => scrollTo(value)}
    textColor={'#3E82FF'} //'#7a44cf'
    selectedColor={'#fff'}
    buttonColor={'#3E82FF'}
    borderColor={'#3E82FF'}
    hasPadding
    options={[
        { label: "User", value: "user"}, 
        { label: "Business", value: "business"} 
    ]}

    style={{
        marginTop: 90,
        marginLeft: 40,
        marginRight:40
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Use the `value` prop

Comment: To clarify a bit: try using value, which seems to take an index.  The docs also say that it will call "onPress".  Not sure what they mean by that.  In general this component seems to be designed mostly for "non-managed" use cases.  good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `initial` prop:

```
initial={whatEverState === 'foo' ? 0 : 1}
```